# How to create a Socket based on the data

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp

I want to know how to create a socket based on the data. For example if the data needs reliability it will create a socket with SOCK_STREAM so it will select TCP, otherwise if it doesn't need any reliability I will use SOCK_DGRAM for UDP.

Can this be achieved using switch or if-else condition?

I am new to this subject. If someone provide a good resource for this I really appreciate.

Comment: Can you answer how you would _programmatically_ determine the type of data without first acquiring it?  This seems like a chicken and egg problem.  Normally, you would design the acquisition method (protocol) to accommodate specific data, not the other way around.  Googling _Sockets programming tutorial for C_ yields 2.9 million answers.  The first 9 or 10 look very relevant.

Comment: I have a table that was created using various data types to use in this situation(In that table I have calculated the throughput,delay and packet drop for data types). So I need to check the suitable protocol according to the table. Using that table we can select the best protocol for a particular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it appears you will ***not*** make the decision which socket type to create by reading the actual data stream, but rather by referring to a table ahead of time.  Is that correct? Then the answer is yes, you can use a branch of some sort to create the appropriate socket/connection type to the IP/port you are connecting to.

***If however*** you wanted to sense the type of data, and then make the decision based on what the byte stream is containing, then you could create a temporary INET socket, read enough bytes to determine content, then decide if you need a different protocol to optimize for your needs. Once the best type of connection has been determined, you can decide to either keep the current connection, or close it, and re-connect with a socket type having a more optimal protocol.  The steps:

***1***  Connect to server using any protocol.
***2***  Analyze first few reads of data content to determine optimal socket protocol.
***3***  If content indicates current protocol is optimal, keep it.
***4***  If content indicates current protocol is not optimal, 
close it, re-open using optimal socket type.

This all assumes you do *not* know what type of data a server you are choosing to connect
to will provide.  ***That seems unlikely***.  It would be more likely you will *know* the type of
data will be served for each IP/port address you connect to, and therefore know which type of connection would be optimal.

Comment: There are several data types like gps,wifi,map data etc. My research project is selecting the best optimal protocol based on the data type (using that table). If we use the same protocol for every data type it might not be the optimal protocol.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create same socket with `SOCK_STREAM` and `SOCK_DGRAM`. You have to choose one. *You* decide protocol, and how your data will get transmitted not your *data*.

Comment: can you explain more plase?

Comment: This is for my research project. I need to decide the protocol dynamically depend on the data. That is why I asked this question.

Comment: @chathura2020 If you need socket programming in detail, you can see my video. It is for Winsock programming. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvcUVYC46mU

Comment: Thanks, I will watch that one also, But do you have any idea to achieve this??

Comment: He isn't asking about 'creat[ing] the same socket with SOCK_STREAM and SOCK_DGRAM'. He is asking about creating one or the other.